# What are the 'big' advantages to have Poco with ORM?

Tags: c#, orm

One advantage that comes to my mind is, if you use Poco classes for Orm mapping, you can easily switch from one ORM to another, if both support Poco.

Having an ORM with no Poco support, e.g. mappings are done with attributes like the DataObjects.Net Orm, is not an issue for me, as also with Poco-supported Orms and theirs generated proxy entities, you have to be aware that entities are actually DAO objects bound to some context/session, e.g. serializing is a problem, etc..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

POCO it's all about loose coupling and testability.

So when you are doing POCO you can test your Domain Model (if your're doing DDD for example) in isolation. You don't have to bother about how it is persisted. You don't need to stub contexts/sessions to test your domain.

Another advantage is that there is less leaky abstractions. Because persistance concerns are not pushed to domain layer. So you are enforcing the SRP principle.

The third advantage I can see is that doing POCO your Domain Model is more evolutive and flexible. You can add new features easier than if it was coupled to the persistance.

I use POCO when I'm doing DDD for example, but for some kind of application you don't need to do DDD (if you're doing small data based applications) so the concerns are not the same.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 I think this is correct, but we should always keep in mind that loose coupling serves many other purposes than just enabling testability: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/07/DependencyInjectionIsLooseCoupling.aspx

Comment: what is this leaky abstractions about anyway? If I build a view based on my EF model, can somebody delete the entry by manipulating the post back data? Or is it just a nice way for companies to say, I dont trust you because you might delete records when I don't want you too. Theeeeen why the heck am I building the ENTIRE project. Its stupid and annoying, makes no sense, spending 80% of time writing abstractions and remapping nicely defined models back and forward, changing the same thing in 4 places. I dont think POCO's are needed unless you writing something like a CMS otherwise.. useless?!

Comment: It depends on the context. I'm not saying it has to be done every time. There are many examples on how CRUD projects works great without the extra overhead. The context is your business. If you're building a referential (saving en editing data) you might just want to use such a CRUD approach. and it's fine. But when you have a rich domain model WITH behavior, the mapping is worth the consideration as it decouple your domain from the persistance concerns.

Answer (score 14):

None. Point. All advantages people like throwing around are advantages that are not important in the big scale of the picture. I rather prefer a strong base class for entity objects that actually holds a lot of integrated code (like throwing property change events when properties change) than writing all that stuff myself. Note that I DID write a (at that time commercially available) ORM for .NET before "LINQ" or "ObjectSpaces" even were existing. I've used O/R mappers like for 15 years now, and never found a case where POCO was really something that was worth the possible trouble.

That said, attributes MAY be bad for other reasons. I rather prefer the Fluent NHibernate approach these days - having started my own (now retired) mapper with attributes, then moved to XML based files.

The "POCO gets me nothing" theme mostly comes from the point that Entities ARE SIMPLY NOT NORMAL OBJECTS. They have a lot of additional functionality as well as limitations (like query speed etc.) that the user should please be aware of anyway. ORM's, despite LINQ, are not replacable anyway - noit if you start using their really interesting higher features. So, at the end you get POCO and still are suck with a base class and different semantics left and right.

I find that most proponents of POCO (as in: "must have", not "would be nice") normally have NOT thought their arguments to the real end. You get all kinds of pretty crappy thoughts, pretty much on the level of "stored procedures are faster than dynamic SQL" - stuff that simply does not hold true. Things like:

- "I want to have them in cases where they do not need saving ot the database" (use a separate object pool, never commit),
- "I may want to have my own functionality in a base class (the ORM should allos abstract entity classed without functionality, so put your OWN base class below the one of the ORM)
- "I may want to replace the ORM with another one" (so never use any higher functionality, hope the ORM API is compatible and then you STILL may have to rewrite large parts).

In general POCO people also overlook the hugh amount of work that acutally is to make it RIGHT - with stuff like transactional object updates etc. there is a TON of code in the base class. Some of the .NET interfaces are horrific to implement on a POCO level, though a lot easier if you can tie into the ORM.

Take the post of Thomas Jaskula here:

> POCO it's all about loose coupling and
>   testability.

That assumes you can test databinding without having it? Testability is mock framework stuff, and there are REALLY Powerful ones that can even "redirect" method calls.

> So when you are doing POCO you can
>   test your Domain Model (if you're
>   doing DDD for example) in isolation.
>   You don't have to bother about how it
>   is persisted. You don't need to stub
>   contexts/sessions to test your domain.

Actually not true. Persistence should be part of any domain model test, as the domain model is there to be persisted. You can always test non-persistent scenarios by just not committing the changes, but a lot of the tests will involve persistence and the failure of that (i.e. invoices with invalid / missing data re not valid to be written to disc, for example).

> Another advantage is that there is
>   less leaky abstractions. Because
>   persistance concerns are not pushed to
>   domain layer. So you are enforcing the
>   SRP principle.

Actually no. A proper Domain model will never have persistence methods in the entities. This is a crap ORM to start with (user.Save ()). OTOH the base class will to things like validation (IDataErrorInfo), handle property update events on persistent filed and in general save you a ton of time.

As I said before, some of the functionality you SHOULD have is really hard to implement with variables as data store - like the ability to put an entity into an update mode, do some changes, then roll them back. Not needed - tell that Microsoft who use that if available in their data grids (you can change some properties, then hit escape to roll back changes).

> The third advantage I can see is that
>   doing POCO your Domain Model is more
>   evolutive and flexible. You can add
>   new features easier than if it was
>   coupled to the persistance.

Non-argument. You can not play around adding fields to a peristet class without handling the persistence, and you can add non-persistent features (methods) to a non-poco class the same as to a poco class.

In general, my non-POCO base class did the following:

- Handle property updates and IDataErrorInfo - without the user writing a line of code for fields and items the ORM could handle.
- Handle object status information (New, Updated etc.). This is IMHO intrinsic information that also is pretty often pushed down to the user interface. Note that this is not a "save" method, but simply an EntityStatus property.

And it contained a number of overridable methods that the entity could use to extend the behavior WITHOUT implementing a (public) interface - so the methods were really private to the entity. It also had some more internal properties like to get access to the "object manager" responsible for the entity, which also was the point to ask for other entities (submit queries), which sometimes was needed.

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I'm trying to say : 

If you use POCO is that you are at least trying to implement a Domain Model. Why I should bother about the mocking frameworks when I want to test the behaviour of my Domain ? If you're relying on the mockings frameworks so you assumes that one should not take care on how the domain is designed.
Doing POCO, I asume that persistance concerns are not in your entities in the Domain Model so there will not be the leaky abstractions from the persistance.
The third, your Domain Model is not always a mirror of a database...

Comment: ...Even if mappings should be updated, you can add behaviour to you DM and not be limited by persistance concerns.

Comment: Well, seriously - I test my domain entity behavior (without persistence) without any mocking. I just never commit at the end ;) So - no queries, no updates commited = no sql generated.

Comment: Finally, a post that makes bloody sense.

Answer (score 8):

POCO support in an ORM is all about separation of concerns, following the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf). With POCO support, an ORM can talk directly to a domain model without the need to "muddy" the domain with data-access specific code. This ensures the domain model is designed to solve only domain-related problems and not data-access problems.

Aside from this, POCO support can make it easier to test the behaviour of objects in isolation, without the need for a database, mapping information, or even references to the ORM assemblies. The ability to have "stand-alone" objects can make development significantly easier, because the objects are simple to instantiate and easy to predict.

Additionally, because POCO objects are not tied to a data-source, you can treat them the same, regardless of whether they have been loaded from your primary database, an alternative database, a flat file, or any other process. Although this may not seem immediately beneficial, treating your objects the same regardless of source can make behaviour easy to predict and to work with.

I chose NHibernate for my most recent ORM because of the support for POCO objects, something it handles very well. It suits the Domain-Driven Design approach the project follows and has enabled great separation between the database and the domain.

Being able to switch ORM tools is not a real argument for POCO support. Although your classes may not have any direct dependencies on the ORM, their behaviour and shape will be restricted by the ORM tool and the database it is mapping to. Changing your ORM is as significant a change as changing your database provider. There will always be features in one ORM that are not available in another and your domain classes will reflect the availability or absence of features.

In NHibernate, you are required to mark all `public` or `protected` class members as `virtual` to enable support for lazy-loading. This restriction, though not significantly changing my domain layer, *has* had an impact on its design.