# Why would I want to use POCO's?

Tags: entity-framework, orm, poco

I currently use the Entity Framework designer to generate my persistance objects and I also user POCO view models for the ASp.NET MVC view.

I've read and listened to a lot of people talking about the good support for POCO's in EF4 as well as POCO's in general but I can't seem to work out what advantage, if any I'll get from using them.

In our application, we WILL be using SQL Server so it's not like we need so separate out for different databases.

Why would I want to use POCO's as opposed to the designer generated classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the 'big' advantages to have Poco with ORM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635953/what-are-the-big-advantages-to-have-poco-with-orm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here :[What are the 'big' advantages to have Poco with ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635953/what-are-the-big-advantages-to-have-poco-with-orm)

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as I didn't see this when I created the question.

Answer (score 2):

POCO offers better extensibility/reuse of your Domain Model as you're not tied to any specific ORM framework.

Answer (score 0):

1. Easier to unit test
2. I find when you have many entities (100+) using the designer is painful and POCO objects are easy to create and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

With POCO's you can "Code First"

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx

Answer (score 0):

+1 for with POCOS you can code first.  In fact you can create and test your entire application before you even write your first line of data access code.  This is how it should be, it's a perfect application of the SRP.  Your domain object should not know or care how they are being persisted.