# Purpose of Entity Framework DBContext Generator

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity, poco, t4

This is probably an obvious question to many but I'm scratching my head over this one.

Can someone explain to me what purpose/advantage generating POCO classes via t4 templates such as the ADO.Net DBContext Generator has over standard EDMX data access?

I understand that they offer extensibility over the entity class definitions, but if a development team is not interested in that what other obvious purpose or advantages do they have?

Thanks

Comment: I believe your question is answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635953/what-are-the-big-advantages-to-have-poco-with-orm

Comment: Thank you for the reference. It has gone a long way toward answering alot of the questions I have. If you reenter as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by ThomasH in the comments the provided link gave me the info I needed.

Comment: Does it really answer your question? The EDMX generates the same POCOs. The question remains for me: Why would you want to use an extra T4 generator if you don't want to modify the generation process?

Comment: I guess there is no other reason: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ613116.aspx.